# How can I avoid declaring a global variable in this R code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, idioms

I am trying to modify [Kyle Gorman's](https://gist.github.com/kylebgorman/6444612) `autoloess` function to be callable as a method in `ggplot2`'s `stat_smooth`. `autoloess` is a simply wrapper which runs `loess` through an optimiser to find the value of `span` which minimises AICc.

**I have created something which runs successfully, but only by using a global variable. Is there a more elegant, idomatic way of programming this?**

My code:

```
AICc.loess <- function(fit) {
  # compute AIC_C for a LOESS fit, from:
  # 
  # Hurvich, C.M., Simonoff, J.S., and Tsai, C. L. 1998. Smoothing 
  # parameter selection in nonparametric regression using an improved 
  # Akaike Information Criterion. Journal of the Royal Statistical 
  # Society B 60: 271â€“293.
  # 
  # @param fit        loess fit
  # @return           'aicc' value
  stopifnot(inherits(fit, 'loess'))
  # parameters
  n <- fit$n
  trace <- fit$trace.hat
  sigma2 <- sum(resid(fit) ^ 2) / (n - 1)
  return(log(sigma2) + 1 + 2 * (2 * (trace + 1)) / (n - trace - 2))
}


.autoloess.magic.w <- NULL
autoloess <- function(formula, data, weights, span=c(0.01, 2.0)) {
  .autoloess.magic.w <- ~weights
  fit <- loess(formula=formula, 
               data=data, 
               weights=.autoloess.magic.w)
  stopifnot(length(span) == 2)
  # loss function in form to be used by optimize
  f <- function(span) AICc.loess(update(fit, span=span))
  # find best loess according to loss function
  res <- update(fit, span=optimize(f, span)$minimum)
  cat(paste("Optimal span:", res$pars$span, "\n"))
  return(res)
}
```

And a quick test:

```
# Test
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1984)
# Create a cubic curve
df <- data.frame(x=1:2500, y=500000 +
                   (-1000*(1:2500)) +
                   ((1:2500)^2)  +
                   -0.00025*((1:2500)^3) +
                   rnorm(2500, sd=60000),
                 ww=runif(2500, min=0, max=10))
# Use loess span
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, weight=ww)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="loess")
```

[image: Loess smooth, with default span of 0.75]

```
# Use autoloess
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, weight=ww)) + geom_point() +  stat_smooth(method="autoloess")
```

[image: Loess smooth, with optimised span of 0.47]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `weight` variable (seems like it is there when the function is called):

```
autoloess <- function(formula, data, weights, span=c(0.01, 2.0)) {

  fit <- loess(formula = formula, 
               data = data, 
               weights=weight)

  stopifnot(length(span) == 2)

  # loss function in form to be used by optimize
  f <- function(span) AICc.loess(update(fit, span=span))
  # find best loess according to loss function
  res <- update(fit, span=optimize(f, span)$minimum)
  cat(paste("Optimal span:", res$pars$span, "\n"))
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Weird that this works. Not sure what is going on with the "weights" parameter now, but perhaps its best not to ask!

Comment: I think in `weights` you get a promise to evaluate to `weight` (I don't know in which environment). Using `weight` directly is a shortcut but it works...